# How to host HTTPS API on LAN

Tags: http, ssl, https, certificate, ca

I'm planning an API that will be used by a client on their internal office networks in multiple separate locations. Each location will have a separate instance installed.

They want it to be secure and running on HTTPS.

What I cant seem to understand how can a HTTPS certificate work when there is no externally facing fully qualified name. eg. MyApiServer.mycompany.com

Instead they will likely just be running it on a server/computer with just a hostname. ie. MyApiServer

The data being transferred is not necessarily sensitive but it places records in a sales system.

If HTTPS is not possible in this scenario whats an alternative method to secure the communication?

Answer (score 0):

The server name has not to be "fully-qualified". For securing the call it will be enough to have the domain specified in URL equal to the domain name specified in certificate.

So your clients would call `https://MyApiServer/endpoint` in your LAN which should cause your service to provide server certificate where the subject would be `MyApiServer`.

Comment: But surely a CA won't issue a certificate to just a hostname, and self signed certs won't be automatically accepted by the connecting clients.

Comment: Since it is internal server there should be internal CA whose root certificate would be installed to client machines. So that all certs issued with that CA would be trusted.

Comment: The is no internal CA. I will be installing this API on a PC in the office and a WIFI Tablet will be accessing it. I could easily create a self signed certificate but thats not advisable in production.

Comment: You can establish local CA like described here https://deliciousbrains.com/ssl-certificate-authority-for-local-https-development/